# MongoDB Aggregation by Shifted Date

Tags: mongodb, datetime, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Is there a way to aggregate by day, but over a 24 hour period that does not go from 12am - 11:59pm?  A sample document looks like this:

```
{
    date: ISODate("2012-11-02T17:04:11.102Z"),
    user: 'testUser',
    orders: 50
}
```

I need to aggregate the # of orders per user per day between 5 pm and 4:59:59.999 pm the next day.  I can get the # of orders per user per day (over a 2 day range) using this:

```
db.hs.aggregate([{
                     $match: {
                         user: 'testUser', 
                         date: {
                             $gte: new Date(2015,0,4,17,0,0,0), 
                             $lt: new Date(2015,0,6,17,0,0,0)
                         }
                     }
                 }, {
                     $group: {
                         _id: {
                             date: {
                                 month: {$month: "$date"},
                                 day: {$dayOfMonth: "$date"},
                                 year: {$year: "$date"}
                             },
                             user: "$user",
                         },
                         totord: {$sum: "$orders"}
                     }
                 }])
```

But this returns 3 results, one for Jan 4 after 5pm, one for Jan 5 all day, and one for Jan 6 before 5pm.  I just don't know how to shift the aggregation to be between 5pm - 4:59pm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you could use the [`$add` aggregation operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/#perform-addition-on-a-date) on your dates in a `$project` aggregation step to get the desired result.

```
db.hs.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            user: 'testUser', 
            date: {
                $gte: new Date(2015,0,4,17,0,0,0), 
                $lt: new Date(2015,0,6,17,0,0,0)
            }
        }
    }, {
        $project: {
            orders: 1,
            user: 1,
            date: { $add: [ "$date", 7*60*60000 ] }
        }
    }, {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                date: {
                    month: { $month: "$date" },
                    day: { $dayOfMonth: "$date" },
                    year: { $year: "$date" }
                },
                user: "$user"
            },
            totord: {$sum: "$orders"}
        }
    }
])
```

I believe this should add 7 hours to the `$date` which should make it so anything after 5PM ends up after midnight the next day.

Comment: Marked as the answer because it does do what I asked.  The problem I discovered is that in order to get the desired effect, I need to add only 2 hours to the date (instead of 7 hours) because the date is stored as GMT and I am in EST which is 5 hours behind GMT.  This is not ideal because for part of the year I will be 4 hours behind due to daylight savings.